# How to customize the ubuntu gnome 3 desktop?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

This is maybe a stupid question, but how can I choose my own background image on ubuntu gnome 3?? I click on Settings -> Background -> then I click on the current background preview to change it but I see only the defaults images! No + symbol to add or something. On the 'Pictures' tab there is nothing to select, I get an empty white page? I am running ubuntu gnome 13.04 3.9.6-030906-generic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A bit easier, or if you don't wanna move the files.

Open the chosen file in the file manager.  It should open with Image Viewer/eog.  Both the Image menu and the right-click context menu have an option called, "Set as Desktop Background."

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Add the background image you wish to use to your pictures folder (~/pictures)
2. Right click your desktop and select "Change Desktop Background"
3. In the upper right region, you should see a drop-down menu with "Wallpapers" currently selected. Click it and select "Pictures Folder"
4. Select your background image
5. Profit!

Comment: Hi Dillmo, thanks for your reply but I don’t have any drop-down menu with "Wallpapers" on the upper right region. I wouldn’t ask if it was so simple, don’t you think? :) When I click on "change background" I can choose only the default ones...